# Batch and Schedulable Help

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I'm trying to create a batch class that updates a set of number fields based on a particular profile that edits them and a schedule class that updates those changes every night at midnight. So far with testing it doesn't look like the code is making the updates and I was wondering if someone could take a look and tell me what I'm doing incorrectly

Batch Class:

```
public class LAM_RollupBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    private Integer recordsProcessed = 0;

    profile userProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Informatica_Connector'];

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Parent_Account_for_LAM__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c, Account_Max_Demand_kw__c, AnnualRevenue FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate = YESTERDAY';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
       List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
        for (Account a : scope) {

           if(userProfile.Id == UserInfo.getProfileId()){

                a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c =  a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_CCF__c;
                a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c = a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c;
                a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c  = a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Usage_kWh__c;       
                a.AnnualRevenue = a.AnnualRevenue;
                a.Account_Max_Demand_kw__c = a.Account_Max_Demand_kw__c;                                   
            }

            recordsProcessed++;            
        }

        update scope;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed');
    }
}
```

Schedulable Class:

```
global class LAM_RollupSchedulable implements Schedulable {

   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      LAM_RollupBatch B = new LAM_RollupBatch();        
    }

    LAM_RollupSchedulable s = new LAM_RollupSchedulable();
    String sch = '0 0 0 * *';
    String jobID  = system.schedule('Update Batch', sch , s);

}
```

Comment: I have a theory the issue lies in your WHERE clause. LastModifiedDate is actually a date time and when you use the `=` operator its looking for records matching the exact day/time. You might want to change it to 
`WHERE LastModifiedDate > YESTERDAY AND LastModifiedDate < TODAY`

Comment: You could also add schedulable to your batch class instead of having a separate class just to make it schedulable.

Comment: N.B. your batch class needs to implement Database.Stateful as otherwise `userProfile` won't have any value when `execute()` is executed

Answer (score 2):

You are missing to execute the Batch class in your Scheduled class. The `execute` in the `LAM_RollupSchedulable` schedulable class should look like as below:

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      LAM_RollupBatch B = new LAM_RollupBatch();       

      // now execute the batch
      Database.executeBatch(B); 
}
```

Additionally, make sure that the User you are using to schedule the batch class has the same Profile Id as expected in the condition in your batch class.